# reactjs - Mongodb - trying to update value in button click

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to update value for the dropdown field once i clicked on the button. It also update in the database also. Am able to update the value properly but at the end it throws data.error alert. I dont know why. Please suggest.

Please find the code below.

```
save(item) {
  ajax({
    url: 'api/save_order',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
     item: JSON.stringify(item)
    }
  }, (data) => {
     if (data.error == null) {
        this.search({});
     } else {
        alert(data.error);
     }
  });
}

handleInputChange(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  const name = target.name;
  const item = this.state.item;
  const status=item.order_status;
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  if(this.state.action == "DeleteOrder")
  {
    item["order_status"] = "DELETED";
    this.setState({ item: item });
    this.props.save(this.state.item);
  }else {
    item[name] = value;
    this.setState({ item: item });
  }
}


handleSave(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.save(this.state.item);
}


if(this.state.action == "DeleteOrder")
{
  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      className="btn btn-primary"
      onClick={ 
        this.handleInputChange
      }
    >
    Delete Order
    </button>
 );}
```

Only am having issue once i clicked on "DeleteOrder" button.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: (data) => {
     if (data.error == null) {
        this.search({});
     } else {
        alert(data.error);
     }

Comment: If condition is failing and going to else part.

Comment: @Karthikeyan yeah but what is error text?

Comment: Am not getting error in text, it throws popup alert, but am getting the expected result. But, i dont know why am getting the alert (error).

Comment: Use console.log(data) in that function and update your question with that log.

Comment: Its printing "Printing Data:::{"error":"error"}"